# Difficulty Inserting Json Dictionary To MSSQL

Tags: python, json, sql-server, insert

I am new to Python, but have a seemingly very simply exercise that I am struggling to figure out.  This is a two part issue.

First: I have a list of Json objects that I am getting from an API.  I am wanting to enter each list item as a row in a Dataframe to preserve that row's json object/dict for storing in a database to allow for editing and reposting. In addition, I am wanting to convert the list into a standard Dataframe (easy enough). In essence, it will be a standard dataframe with the row's raw json contained as an additional column.  I've managed to accomplish this by joining a Series to a Dataframe, but I am relying on the index to join. My first question is whether the join can be done based not just on the index, but to join based on the 'id' value in the dataframe to the 'id' contained in each element in the json object/dict in the list?  The rationale being that in doing so, I'd eliminate order concerns and I'd be 100% sure the json object is associated with the correct dataframe row.

Second: As I mentioned above, I've simply joined the series to the dataframe using the index, which works in this case because the both use the same 'data' list.  The output looks good when I print but when I go to insert it into MSSQL, it does not like the json dictionary ('Json_Series' column).  The insert works fine when I just eliminate that field. I could see how an inline fstring for the insert concatenation might work if you did some type of cast or convert on the dict, but I will be doing this for many APIs so I am trying to keep from having to write custom insert language (i.e. would like to rely on a to_sql or equivalent method/class/library).  I have also tried changing the column with .astype('str') prior to insert, but that doesn't work as has been documented elsewhere.

The error I get is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=dict', 'HY105')
[SQL: INSERT INTO dbo.[TestInsert_JsonObject_Python] ([Json_Series], id, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ({'id': 1, 'value': 2}, 1, 2, {'id': 3, 'value': 4}, 3, 4)]
```

Clearly, it is the first parameter and it sees it as a dictionary.  Removing that column resolves the issue.

Here is what I've tried.  This shows the Series (df), the dataframe (df2) and the combined join (inner_merged'). The join is vulnerable in the future to order if I were to join different lists.  I am needing the join to reference the internal 'id' in the json dict when joining against the dataframe's 'id' column  The combined join ('inner_merged') is however in the form that I'd like to be able to just insert into SQL.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

data = [{"id": 1, "value": 2}, {"id": 3, "value": 4}]
df = pd.Series(data, name='Json_Series')
df2= pd.DataFrame(data)
inner_merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df)
print(df2)
# inner_merged['Json_Series'] = inner_merged['Json_Series'].astype('str')
print(inner_merged)
```

Here is the MSSQL table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestInsert_JsonObject_Python](
    [Json_Series] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] int Null,
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestInsert_NoJsonObject_Python](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] int Null,
) 
GO
```

Here is the insert - the first one without the json object and the second with:

```
server = 'enteryourserver'
database = 'enteryourdatabase'
username = 'enteryourusername'
password = 'enteryourpassword'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
table1 = 'TestInsert_NoJsonObject_Python'
table2 = 'TestInsert_JsonObject_Python'
schema = 'dbo'

connection_string = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)

df2.to_sql(table1, con=engine, schema= schema, if_exists='replace', index=False)
inner_merged.to_sql(table2, con=engine, schema= schema, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

As I mentioned, I am totally new to this so any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You need to `json.dumps` the dict to json string

Comment: Your column that will contain the Json is just expecting a string - so it's not that you're actually inserting an array into that column, you just need to insert the string of Json, eg. "{'id': 1, 'value': 2}" as the parameter value

Comment: Thank you both.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that transformation.  I've done so manually and it will insert now, so I am trying to figure out how to manipulate the Json_Series column to be a json string prior to inserting.  What I am running into now is that to use the inner_merged.Json_Series = json.dumps(inner_merged.Json_Series) to transform the dataframe column prior to the insert give the error:  TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable.  I've tried jsonpickle but I could not see how to get that to work either.  Clearly I need to serialize it, however.

Comment: OK.  I've solved the json.dumps() issue.  I did not realize that python was manipulating the data list to begin with and thought it was a function of the dataframe.  I solved by creating a new list and iterating and appending to the new list using the json.dump(item).                                                   
list_json_string = []
for index, item in enumerate(data):
    list_json_string.append((json.dumps(item)))